# Netlify Deploying React JS app but I can' get any page after signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, deployment, netlify

Edit: Fixed. problem was api and couldn't think like that. i will delete this post soon. thank you

This is my first question on Stackoverflow.

I created an app in React JS and Ruby on Rails. I deployed my ruby api to heroku and it's working well. Also I deployed my react app to Netlify and I can get login page. But after loginpage i can get main page for 1 second and then it's gone. This is my first exprience with netlify and about deploying. my code is like this for login:

```
render() {
return (<main>
  {
    this.isLoggedIn() 
    ? <>
      <Navi checkNavi = {this.logOutUser}/>
      <Dashboard token={ this.state.token } loggedInUserId={ this.state.loggedInUserId } />
      </> 
    : <SignIn logInUser={ this.logInUser } />
  }
```

it means if user already loggedin get  Navi and Dashboard component else get singin page. That's why if someone try to enter my app singin page coming at first.

also i upload a video to youtube about my problem you can check it out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgfFnNYm5YA&feature=youtu.be

and my app page:https://pensive-knuth-196490.netlify.com/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out your page and for me, it appears to be fully functional. The news dashboard loads up fine. Have you tried it again since?

Comment: Hey Xavia,yes i fix it. The problem was about api, thank you so much for checking out.